# Randomize multi user for once MySQL to fix Exceeded max_questions Error

Tags: mysql, database, drupal-7

original link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2323373

Hi I found this code for the drupal to fix the Exceeded max_questions Error, but I was unable to insert it to the settings.php, it keep giving me error message. I wonder someonce please help me to fix it. Please be specify because i have no knowlege about code, i just an ending user. Thanks in advance.

let say my user name was mimosa I create another 4 user name I get mimosa_1, mimosa_2, mimosa_3, mimosa_4 I given all user same password: "allsamepassword".
Here is the original settings.php for my database for drupal 7

```
    $databases = array (
   'default' => 
    array (
   'default' => 
   array (
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'mimosa_database',
  'username' => 'mimosa',
  'password' => 'allsamepassword',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
   ),
   ),
   );
```

This is the instruction: 
Steps:

1. Create a few MySQL users named sequentially eg. username1, username2, username3, username4 (4 users should be sufficient; if not, add more)
2. Set the same MySQL password on all the users
3. Allow the users access to your database
4. In the site's settings.php file section for database connection:

Here is the code for multi user for once datebase to solve the Exceeded max_questions Error, could some once please input the user name and database name in to the code below in the right way so i can use the code for my website

```
 # randomize MySQL user number
$muser = mt_rand ( 1 , 4 );
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
'driver' => 'mysql',
'database' => 'dbname',
'username' => 'username' . $muser,
'password' => 'password',
'host' => 'host',
'prefix' => '',
);
```